# Enumerable Range is not working quite right

Tags: c#

I have an enumerable range, and what I initially wanted to do with the range was loop through the stored list and get the minStop (minimum stoping point) and maxStart (max tarting pint) But I am only geting the min range and max range in my enumerable range and it is not giving me the values that I need. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.  PLEASE!

```
List<Grades> ranges = new List <Grades>();
var strGrades = "40-50, 55-62, 65-72, 80-82, 85-92, 95-99, 110-115";
var splitGrades = strGrades.Split(char.Parse(","));
foreach(var item in splitGrades)
{
    var splitAgain = items.Split(char.Parse("-"));
    var myMax = Math.Max(int.Parse(splitAgain[0]), int.Parse(splitAgain[1]));
    var myMin = Math.Max(int.Parse(splitAgain[0]), int.Parse(splitAgain[1]));

    //my enumerable list   
    var erange = Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(myMax), int.Parse(myMax)).ToList()
    foreach (var maxrange in erange)
    {
       for (int q = myMin; q < maxrange; q++)
        {
         //custom extension method for Between
         if (!q.Between((myMin), (myMax), true))
         {
          //Public class Grades{public int Start, get; set }                  
            ranges.Add(new Grades()
            {
              Start= q,
            });
         }
       }
     }        
  }
 return ranges;
}
```

Can anyone please show me how to get my enumerable range to get my minStop value (For example: first set of grades: 40-50, my min stop value would be 50, then get my next set of grade ranges 55-62, my max starting value would be 55, so I am looking to get the range from 50- 55, I need the last value from the each set and the beginning value for the set after that. I hope I am clear.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: have you ever read the msdn/docu?

Comment: `char.Parse(",")`? Why not use char literals instead: `','` or `'-'`?

Comment: You have a range of Max to Max.

Comment: @ Andreas Niedermair... No on this subject. And your statement is quite pointless!

Answer (score 9):

If you look up the documentation of [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) you'll see that the second aparameter is the count, and not the maximum.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count)
```

So you need to pass `max - min + 1` as second parameter, assuming your maximum is inclusive.

You'll also need to pass the minimum as first parameter, not the maximum.

And one more bug is that you calculate `myMin` as the maximum and not the minimum of the limits.

Comment: How would I calculate my min as the minimum limits? From my code what should I change to do this?

Comment: ` var myMin = Math.Max(...` well you could replace the word `Max` with the word `Min` in this formula....

Answer (score 1):

First of all to find `Min` it should be

```
var myMin = Math.Min(int.Parse(splitAgain[0]), int.Parse(splitAgain[1]));

Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(myMax),int.Parse(myMax))
```

This will make a enumerable starting from n and having n length.

It should be

```
Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(myMax), int.Parse(myMax) - int.Parse(myMin) + 1)
```

Your code should be

```
List<Grades> ranges = new List <Grades>();
var strGrades = "40-50, 55-62, 65-72, 80-82, 85-92, 95-99, 110-115";
var splitGrades = strGrades.Split(char.Parse(","));
foreach(var item in splitGrades)
{
    var splitAgain = items.Split(char.Parse("-"));
    int myMax = Math.Max(int.Parse(splitAgain[0]), int.Parse(splitAgain[1]));
    int myMin = Math.Min(int.Parse(splitAgain[0]), int.Parse(splitAgain[1]));

    //my enumerable list   
    var erange = Enumerable.Range(myMax, myMax - myMin + 1).ToList()
    foreach (var maxrange in erange)
    {
       for (int q = myMin; q < maxrange; q++)
        {
         //custom extension method for Between
         if (!q.Between((myMin), (myMax), true))
         {
          //Public class Grades{public int Start, get; set }                  
            ranges.Add(new Grades()
            {
              Start= q,
            });
         }
       }
     }        
  }
 return ranges;
}
```